# Anylogic, parameter variation experiment pipeline source error

Tags: python, anylogic, vehicle-routing

I am trying to create a parameter variation based on a single python script run using the pipeline jar. I manually added a variable called 'pyCommunicator ' of the type other 'PyCommunicator' with initial value new 'PyCommunicator()'.

In the 'initial experiment set' block of the properties section, I import the python file via 'pyCommunicator.run("import GA");'
However, when I try to run the parameter variation I get the error code "PyCommunicator.java:669' indicating that the source code is not present. It also states '669 is not a valid line number in com.anylogic.libraries.pypeline.PyCommunicator'

When I add the jar file at the 'Change Attached Source' option the error does not change. The jar file is in the same folder as the anylogic and python files. I am not sure why the error occurs now. Has anybody experienced this issue before?

[image]

[image]

This is what it shows if you click on the error:
[image]

Comment: When you click on the `PyCommunicator.java:669`, what does it show?

Comment: Hi Yashar, i added a image to the rest of my questions containing the error message.

Comment: Thank you..if you put something trivial like "import numpy as np", does it work?

Comment: No, I get the same error unfortunately.

Comment: This means that it is not a folder issue. Let's step back..does it work in the normal simulation experiment? Have you tried it?

Comment: Following [these](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rxHD5MuDUvs&ab_channel=AnyLogic) steps.

Comment: Hi, yes for a normal simulation it works fine. The values from the python script are embedded within the anylogic parameters and I can run the model. However, for the parameter variation experiment, this is different. Here I cannot add the python Communicator block and have to manually add a variable (see page 3 https://www.anylogic.com/upload/pdf/q-and-a-with-writeups.pdf).

Comment: Following the steps from the video by the way!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240724/discussion-between-yashar-ahmadov-and-bas-lindeboom).

Comment: The suggestion I made in my question to use a single python run for multiple simulations is not possible, see https://github.com/t-wolfeadam/AnyLogic-Pypeline/discussions/24 for a more thorough explanation.